# Parse error in pattern in declaration foo (5+5:x:xs) = x

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

The code works as expected if I replace 5+5 with 10. What is the problem here? Am I allowed to use the + operator inside a pattern? Is it considered a n+k pattern? I know those are not allowed on Haskell 2010, so that might be the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't make sense as an `n+k` pattern. For an `n+k` pattern to match, `n - k` must be non-negative, and `n` must be a variable (you'll even get an error if you try and write an `n+k` pattern as `k+n`).
Does it make sense as a regular pattern? If it did, then I should be able to replace the `5`s with variables and still have a a valid pattern, but what would the values of `m` and `n` be for the pattern `(m+n:x:xs)` in the case of the list `[3,4,5]`?

Comment: You could match the result of an arbitrary expression with `ViewPatterns`, like `foo (((== 5 + 5) -> True) : x : xs) = x`, but this would be considered unusual, especially for such a simple expression; generally `ViewPatterns` are meant for working with abstract data types like `Data.Vector`, or situations where you want to, well, view a data structure in an alternate way, like `lastIsOne (reverse -> 1 : _) = True; lastIsOne _ = False`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's true. In general, a valid pattern in Haskell should contain only constructors, literals and variables that you bind to, but not just any functions. ([Haskell/Pattern matching](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching))

`(+)` is a function, so patterns containing it simply shouldn't be valid. The reason why the so-called "n+k pattern" was actually a thing is that it was introduced as a syntactic sugar (See [Wikipedia's entry on Haskell 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)#Haskell_2010)). Apart from that, `(5+5:x:xs)` as a pattern should be as invalid as `[x, y, z] ++ xs`.

To give my own two cents, this could be another reason why it isn't allowed, even with two literals being the operands of `(+)`. Haskell allows you to do this if the `5+5` pattern is to pass the compiler:

```
foo x = let 5 + 5 = 11 in (\(5+5:xs) -> x ++ xs)
```

Now is it clear at compile time anymore that `5 + 5 = 10`?

Comment: `:` is also a function that's not a constructor. IMO it should be clearly stated that pattern matching  is just a primitive language feature.

Comment: `:` **is** a constructor.

Comment: You can also do `let 2 = 3 in ...` without problems (thanks to laziness), so I don't think the last argument works.

Comment: @Franky whoa. Didn't know that.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Yeah, that's true, but I'm trying to show that (5+5) cannot be safely simplified to 10 at compile time so this pattern is invalid no matter how you try to work around it. On the other hand, if we have `let 2 = 3 in \(2:xs) -> xs`, since pattern matching itself takes place at runtime, that'll be totally fine.

Comment: If syntax for `n+k` patterns was `pattern+integer`, so `5+5` was valid, I don't see any difference: `let 5+5 = 11 in ...` would just be another failing pattern match which is never evaluated and doesn't affect the meaning of the `\(5+5:xs) -> x ++ xs` part.

Comment: But there would be another problem: a conflict between `n+k` patterns and defining a function named `(+)`. Actually, maybe this `let` would define a `(+)` function, as it does now, but then again it doesn't affect the lambda because the definition of `n+k` patterns uses `Prelude.(+)` and not any other function with the same name.

Answer (score 1):

According to 3.17.1 in https://www.haskell.org/definition/haskell98-report.pdf, pattern syntax only allows `var + integer`, so `5+5` shouldn't be a legal pattern in Haskell 98 either.